# How do I put an article in a block?

Tags: blocks, nodes

I don't think I understand Drupal too well yet.  I have an article.  In the theme I chose it has the various blocks.  How do I put an article on a given block area of a theme?

I see the modules I can assign to a block in a specific region, but I have things articles I want to put in the block.  I don't need who's online, recent comments, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to put a node, where in your case it will be a node from an article content type, you can use the [node as block](https://drupal.org/project/nodeasblock) module.

You also have other module options, including:

- https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock/
- https://drupal.org/project/nodesinblock

These modules allow you to add your nodes inside a block. Afterwards, you can configure which block to show in which region on the block administration page. For example if you want to hide the 'who is online block' simply set the region for the block to none and it will not show up any more.

Comment: Why would it be so hard to add an article to a block?  Is it because it is more of a themeing issue, that is hard coding the article link into a region?

Comment: @johnny It's not what would be considered 'core' functionality (for example I think I've done it maybe once or twice ever out of dozens of Drupal sites I've built). That's where Drupal shines - all it takes to get that functionality is to install a module. It's an extra step, but one that you'll get used to quickly.

Comment: @johnny And to counter Clive, all sites are different.  I routinely need to do things like this on the sites we build for clients.

Comment: @clive Can you show me a demo site that doesn't have something like what I'm asking?  I am having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: I generally prefer to use [Bean](https://drupal.org/project/bean) to create content as blocks. The module is similar to the core Node module, but is tailored towards building and maintaining blocks instead of pages. Usually if I want to display a node in a block, I'll use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to display and add additional logic (such as displaying the most recent node of type `article`, for example).

Comment: the first mentioned `node as block` module is Drupal 4.7/5 whose last commit was in 2010. Should it be in the answer, or should it simply be noted. I think anyone wanting a Drupal 5 module would surely mention it

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if there is any shortcut to put the article into Block, but usually I use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) for that. After installing Views Module

1. create new Views and select ***content*** of type ***Article***
2. Check on **Create a Block** and *Continue and Edit*
3. In Fields, Select the fields you want to display eg: Article Title, Description, etc.
4. Use the **Filter** to filter results.

If you want to display only the latest Article, then use **Sort** by ***Post Date Desc*** and in **Pager** settings display max items to ***1*** with ***No Pagination*** option.

Go to **Structure->Blocks** and select your theme and you can enable/disable what blocks you want to display and where. If you are unsure about the regions in theme then click **Demonstrate Block Regions**

This looks one heck of a task, but playing around **Views** would make you more comfortable with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to dive into the "panels module way" of layouting your pages, then you will find that it comes closer to your way of thinking.
Traditionaly, blocks are not for "putting the article content into my theme". Blocks are for the fluff around your content. (like e.g. Who is online)
But the "panels approach" will replace the "classic block way of doing things" in your drupal.
Panels will instead support your approach of "put the article's content here -- like I would place a block."